# Writing data to JavaFX Tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have never used tableview before and I am quite new to with Java and JavaFX.  I tried to mirror an example but since the data is coming from a db client created in house I couldn't copy it exactly.  Anyway, my data is going into the table but its entering as what looks like a csv data and each column is not getting put into its respective column.  Here is a screenshot to clarify my question:

[image]

Getting columns here

```
   for (Column col : drs.getColumns()){
        TableColumn tblCol = new TableColumn(col.getName());
        tblCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> p) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().toString());
            }
        });
         table.getColumns().addAll(tblCol);
    }
```

Getting the rows here:

```
while (drs.hasNextRow()) {
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < drs.getColumns().length; i++) {
        row.add(drs.getNextRow().getItem(i) + "");
    }
    data.add(row);
}
```

And here is where I fail at sending the data to the table.

```
table.setItems(data);
System.out.println("dis is data: " +data);
```

the data prints like so:

```
dis is data: [[data, data, data....], [data, data, data....], [data, data, data....]]
```

It takes each [row] and puts it into each column for each record.  I am assuming I need the data to look like:

```
[[data], [data], [data]....[data]], [[data], [data], [data]....[data]], [[data], [data], [data]....[data]]
```

```
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("everything is broken");
    }
}
```

So, I am lost.  I don't know what I am doing and I'd appreciate any help that you can offer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TableView` all the data in a row is associated with a item. The `TableColumn.cellValueFactory` is used to select the "part" of a item that should be shown in the column. Therefore you should use it to select the value:

```
TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = ...
int index = 0;
for (Column col : drs.getColumns()) {
    final int columnIndex = index++;
    TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> tblCol = new TableColumn(col.getName());
    tblCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> p) {
            return Bindings.stringValueAt(p.getValue(), columnIndex);
        }
    });
    table.getColumns().add(tblCol);
}
```

Here the [`Bindings.stringValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#stringValueAt-javafx.collections.ObservableList-int-) is used to select the element form the `ObservableList`.

Also you need to use one row per row:

```
while (drs.hasNextRow()) {
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Row sourceRow = drs.getNextRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < drs.getColumns().length; i++) {
        row.add(Objects.toString(sourceRow.getItem(i)));
    }
    data.add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I got it working however now when I enter another query it appends the new query to the right of the old one in the table.

Comment: @anshanno: I don't know what your input data structure is, but when in doubt you can clear the items and columns of the `TableView` before setting new data...